# extract query string param value in RewriteRule

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite, cookies

I'm writing an apache 2.4 Rewrite rule in order to remove a query string param and create a cookie from its value.

eg:

```
http://example.com/?param1=value1&my_param=my_value&param2=value2
```

to

```
http://example.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

i'm successfully using apache RewriteRule to set a cookie
but i would like to set the prepended query string param value as cookie value.

if i remove **my_param=my_value** from the query string

i want the value of the cookie to be **my_value**

this is what i've done so far, the only problem is that i can't figure out 
out to retrieve "my_value".

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*)(?:^|&)utm_source=(?:[^&]*)((?:&|$).*)

RewriteCond %1%2 (^|&)([^&].*|$)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%2 [CO=utm_source:my_value_here:.example.org:1440:/,R=301]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

my mistake was the 301 that perform caching, i get it working with a simpler rewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)my_param=([^&]+)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%3 [CO=my_param:%2:.example.com:1440:/,R=302]
```